# How to build lucene index in a mapReduce way?

Tags: hadoop, solr, lucene, indexing, mapreduce

I am building a small image similarity search application with hadoop. I decide to use [LIRE](http://www.lire-project.net) which in [this](https://code.google.com/p/lire/source/browse/trunk/samples/simpleapplication/src/net/semanticmetadata/lire/sampleapp/Indexer.java?r=58) demo code, it uses lucene indexWriter to write index to a local disk. What I have done now is making my reducers generate the LIRE records. but how to make reducers write these records to a Lucene index file in HDFS? I googled and find some tools like solrCloud, Blur, but there is no good document and code example to show how to do it.

Does anyone know some good reference?

PS. I notice there is a question with similarity title, but it was from 3 years ago, and the answers are not clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Solr 4.7 there is a option do index using HDFS using kite morpholines code. This is part of Solr distribution now (>4.7). Look at this JIRA for more information. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5729

Also look at the earlier git repository https://github.com/markrmiller/solr-map-reduce-example